# Read remote file, and output to browser. Work with text and html. Don't work with images. NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get, http-get

I have a little code:

```
var target = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CXfX.png'; //For example, a .PNG image

//Testing with text/html and text/plain and image/png
res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'image/png' );//res is response of current request

http.get( url.parse( target ), function( response ) {

   var data;

    response.on( 'data', function( chunk ) {

        if( !data ) data = chunk; else data += chunk;

    }).on('end', function() {

        res.send( data );

    });

});
```

Which fetches data from `target`, and display it to the browser, depends on the `Content-Type` I set. As of now, it works very well in fetching document and display it as HTML or plain text. However, when changing the target to a direct image URL, and change `Content-Type` to corresponding type of file (such as `image/png` or `image/jpeg`), the image is broken. Even when I tried to download the image, its size (Content-Length) is just like the original size, but no program can open it because it is broken. I'm not quite sure how it works with text and html but not with images (even though the `Content-Type` has been set correctly)?

Comment: I think you need to show an example of the exact type of data you are trying to pull down.

Comment: @James: I edited it to an image link instead. That is what I'm looking to being able to do. It's PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pipe the response instead unless you really need to buffer it for some reason. Example:

```
var target = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CXfX.png';
http.get(target, function(response) {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    return response.pipe(res);
  }

  // drain the response and discard it
  response.resume();
  res.send(response.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: Hi! What does that response.pipe() really do and how is it different from the Buffer()?

Comment: See the [node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) for information about `pipe()`.